# How do I get rid of this initialization from incompatible pointer type warning/error?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to write a linked list program in C, however I keep on getting an initalization from incompatible pointer type warning/error.  How do I get rid of this?  And could you explain what is wrong?  What follows is a simplified version of my program:

```
typedef struct node
{
int contents;
struct Node *nextNode;
} Node;

int main(void)
{
//.......Other code here......
  Node *rootNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  rootNode->nextNode = NULL;
//.......Other code here......
  addNode(rootNode);
}      

addNode(Node *currentNode)
{
//.....Other code here....
  Node *nextNode = (currentNode->nextNode);   //Error on this line
// ....Other code here...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: casting malloc is not appreciated in C. If you have to do so , never forget to add stdlib.h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `struct node *` not `struct Node *` in your `struct node`:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int contents;
    struct node *nextNode; /* here */
} Node;
```

And don't cast the return value from `malloc`, it is not needed.

Comment: good catch. If this solved it, @user950891, you must have a `struct Node` which is something different in your code, too. You should review your naming conventions. For me the easiest is to always have the same `typedef` identifier as the `struct` tag. If you had `typedef struct Node Node;` at the first declaration the compiler would have identified your error better.

Comment: @Jens: Not necessarily. user950891's original `struct` will compile all by itself. I can't quote chapter and verse from the standard to justify it but `gcc -Wall` is happy with it.